# Are all pdf's L-infinity by definition?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

From [here](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall18/sta711/lec/wk-05.pdf):

> Fix a probability space $(Ω,\mathcal F, P)$ and, for any real number $p > 0$ (not necessarily an integer) and let $L^p$ or $L^p(Ω, \mathcal F, P),$ pronounced “ell pee”, denote the vector space of real-valued (or sometimes complex-valued) random variables $X$ for which $E|X|^p < ∞.$

Random variables are functions from $X: \Omega \to \mathbb R,$ and their expectation in continuous rv's is $\mathbb E[X]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x f_X(x) dx,$ with $f_X(x)$ being the probability density function.

Since pdf's $f_X(x)$ integrate to $1$ is it correct to say that all of them belong to $L^\infty$?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with expectation.  The fact that  pdf's are integrable means that they're in $L^{\color{red}1}$

Comment: $L^{\infinity}$ just means the function is bounded. This is not necessarily true for pdf’s.

Comment: @Eric That is helpful! Thank you. So it can still integrate to 1, but blow up.

Answer (score 1):

Consider random variable $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ with probability distribution
$$\mu(X\leq t)=\begin{cases}
0 & t \leq 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx & t \in (0,1] \\
1 & t > 1
\end{cases}$$
with associated probability density
$$f_X(t)=\begin{cases}
0 & t \leq 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}& t \in (0,1] \\
0 & t > 1
\end{cases}$$
The density is integrable but unbounded so $f \notin L^\infty$

Comment: Clear as day. Is there any $L^p$ function space to which all pdf's belong to?

Comment: As stated in the comments, the pdfs belong to $\mathcal{L}^1(\lambda)$, the space of Lebesgue integrable functions